# Angular2-NULL Exception-DataTable Filter on Keyup.ENTER event-Server side filtering

Tags: angular, primeng

Whenever user presses ‘ENTER’ key in the search textbox of PRIME NG Data table (i have used (keyup.enter) event of Angular2 to fire the service method) , its ending up with a null exception. The actual operation involves that when user enters the data in the filter text boxes and presses 'ENTER' key, the filtering of data will be carried out at the server side (Asp.NET WEB API) and the data will be showed in the GRID.

Console.log is as follows:

```
core.umd.js:2844 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at DataTable._filter (http:.../node_modules/primeng/components/datatable/datatable.js:773:43)
    at DataTable.filter (http:.../node_modules/primeng/components/datatable/datatable.js:755:14)
```

component.html

```
                <p-dataTable #userTable [value]="vContactsModels" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelectGridEvent('user')" resizableColumns="true"
                             [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" totalRecords="120" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30]" [responsive]="true" (onFilter)="onTableFiltered()" (keyup.enter)="filterDataFromServer($event)">>
                    <p-column field="UID" header="UID" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true"></p-column>
```

I am using the latest version of PRIME NG (1.1.4) and Angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got to know the problem in the code, that is, we should not set the value for the p-datable to NULL anywhere in the component.ts file. In this case "vContactsModels" was set to NULL before loading the data in the  ngOnInit() method. Happy coding :)